# how do i find all the links of videos and add option of "Play Video" or "Download Video"

Tags: javascript, php, html, video, video-streaming

I'm using php in order to crawl and generate video links from the internet and now i want to add  option of "Play Video" or "Download Video" when a video link is found  also add a video player when play video option is selected.

for example visit this site
http://filemile.ga/new.php?search=arrow&view=linkfile

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="n">Name</th>
      <th class="m">Last Modified</th>
      <th class="s">Size</th>
      <th class="t">Type</th>
      <th>Play/Download???</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="n">
        <a href="http://example.com">Parent Directory</a>
      </td>
      <td class="m">&nbsp;</td><td class="s">- &nbsp;</td>
      <td class="t">Directory</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="n">
        <a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv">Big_Buck_Bunny_small.ogv</a>
      </td>
      <td class="m">&nbsp;</td><td class="s">4.5MB</td>
      <td class="t">video</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="n">
        <a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">bunny.mp4</a>
      </td>
      <td class="m">&nbsp;</td><td class="s">1.8MB</td>
      <td class="t">video</td>
      <td class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="n">
        <a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm">bunny.webm</a>
      </td>
      <td class="m">&nbsp;</td><td class="s">2.8MB</td>
      <td class="t">video</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How do i do this?

Comment: I can't really get what you want to achieve. Do you want to achieve a webpage like the link you posted or is that your webpage and you want to add a DOWNLOAD and PLAY button? If it's your webpage and you want to add the buttons please show some code

Comment: yes that's my webpage, sorry i can't show my code. I just want to know if there's a way after the page is loaded a javascript finds all the link from the page and add play or download button next to it @KANAYOAUSTINKANE

Comment: Okay, I don't really know how to start if you don't show your code because I don't know how you got all the links and your results. You don't need to show all your codes, just show the relevant codes, how you got your links and results. If you got it from your database then just show your database query and its results

Comment: Simply create two anchors `PLAY`, `DOWNLOAD`. The download should do what is already doing (download a mkv video)...or to make sure you can use create a dynamic `a` element, set it's `download` attribute to the video link `dynA.href= movieURI;` and trigger a click like `dynA.click()` For the play button you can create a HTML5 `<video>` element and send the video source to playback `<source src="something.mkv" type="video/mp4">`. Good luck with the legal stuff...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  can you tell me how to preg_match all possible video links in an array?

Comment: @Azhar `preg_match` what? If you're building (I see you already do) the table `<td class="n">` than that link inside (if the extension is i.e: `.mkv`) you have the URI. What you need is to append to that `<tr>` another TD cell with `<button data-download="something.mkv">Download</button>` and `<button data-play="something.mkv">Play Video</button>`. Than in JS target any `"[data-download]"` or `[data-play]` element and trigger the needed functions (`playvideo()` / `download()` ) . Additionally you could hide the original URL and download as packets....

Comment: what i'm trying to do with pregmatch is get all the links of videos inside an array and recreate the table with having play and download button inside of it . @RokoC.Buljan    tell me how can i hide the original URL and download as packets?

Comment: @Azhar you said the page is yours. And as I can see you already managed to create the tables with links. That means you already have available the links in the PHP. If that's not true or you're hiding info, than you could do is using JS. After PHP serves the page, scrape all links with JS and create the buttons.

Comment: The page is mine @RokoC.Buljan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the TD's `.n` Anchor. Extract the `href` and get the text.
prepare an empty TD for every TR and do like (Example using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)):

```js
function isVideo(uri) {
  return /\.(webm|mkv|avi|mp4|mpeg|mpg|ogv)/.test(uri);
}

$("tbody tr").each(function(){

  var $tdDownload = $(this).find(".d"),
      $tdName = $(this).find(".n"),
      $tdNameA = $tdName.find("a"),
      uri = $tdNameA.prop("href"),
      ext = uri.split(".").pop(),
      name = $tdNameA.text(),
      name2 = name.replace(/[\w\s]/ig,"");

  if(!isVideo(uri)) return; // Do nothing. Else...

  var pl = "<a class='play' href='"+ uri +"'>Play</a>",
      dl = "<a class='download' href='"+ uri +"' download='"+ name2 +"'>Download</a>";
  $tdDownload.append(pl, dl);

});


var videoPopup = document.getElementById("videoPopup");



function playVideo(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  videoPopup.innerHTML = "";

  var src = this.getAttribute("href");
  var ext = src.split(".").pop();
  var type = "video/"+ ext.replace("ogv","ogg").replace("mkv","x-matroska");

  var video = document.createElement('video');
  var source = document.createElement('source');

  source.setAttribute("type", type);
  source.setAttribute("src", src);
  video.controls = true;
  video.appendChild(source);
  videoPopup.appendChild(video);
  video.play();

}


$("table").on("click", ".play", playVideo);
```

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th{
  text-align: left;
}
th, td{
  padding: 4px 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
td.d a{
  line-height:16px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="n">Name</th>
      <th class="m">Last Modified</th>
      <th class="s">Size</th>
      <th class="t">Type</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="n">
        <a href="http://example.com">Parent Directory</a>
      </td>
      <td class="m">&nbsp;</td><td class="s">- &nbsp;</td>
      <td class="t">Directory</td>
      <td class="d"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="n">
        <a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv">Big_Buck_Bunny_small.ogv</a>
      </td>
      <td class="m">&nbsp;</td><td class="s">4.5MB</td>
      <td class="t">video</td>
      <td class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="n">
        <a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">bunny.mp4</a>
      </td>
      <td class="m">&nbsp;</td><td class="s">1.8MB</td>
      <td class="t">video</td>
      <td class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="n">
        <a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm">bunny.webm</a>
      </td>
      <td class="m">&nbsp;</td><td class="s">2.8MB</td>
      <td class="t">video</td>
      <td class="d"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<div id="videoPopup"></div>
```

Comment: wow this is amazing i'll definitely try this, but is it possible to play the video just below that row and not below the table? @Roko

Comment: @Azhar yes. You can even make the `#videoPopup` as an actual popup... I thought you'll see how I called it and you'll get that idea all alone ;)

Comment: Thanks @Roko i'll figure it out,  I've just started learning php and JavaScript 2 weeks ago  .. can i ask you more questions in the future if you don't mind ?

Comment: @Azhar I don't mind. You're welcome, just I hope you'll not get into legal issues with what you're doing ;) good luck

Comment: legal issues? i'm not hosting any content i just provide links like Google does . :)